# How to find text strings in a .xxx file

Tags: string, file

I'm working on a program that needs to find a tag in a .xxx file to just tell me if it exists or not in the file. I've been doing quite a bit of troubleshooting but I've realized there are three key things I don't know:

1. What a .xxx file is
2. Where to find help on how to work with .xxx files (Google didn't return anything useful)
3. How to read a string out of a .xxx file

I'm looking for help with these 3 things - specifically the 3rd, but help on the other two would mean I don't have to ask more questions later! I'm not in need of troubleshooting help yet - I'm not too worried about making my code run at this moment. This is more for reference and general knowledge so I don't have to ask 100 more questions about tedious specifics later on.

So, if anyone out there knows anything about these three problems, or has any knowledge on .xxx files, can you help me out?

(If you happen to know the code to do this, I'm writing in C#)

Comment: What is the file's encoding? UTF-8? UTF-16? Apart from possible encoding mismatches, your code is fine, by the way. What happens when you step through it? What lines do you see? Does your tag have the same case as what's in the file?

Comment: Any chance it's a character case mismatch problem?  Something where your text editor is searching case-insensitively so it's finding things that `String.Contains` wouldn't?

Comment: When I open up the file in Notepad++ it says Encode in UTF-8 without BOM. I'm a pretty new programmer, what do you mean by step through it? And the tag is the exact same case.

Comment: We can't know what file format you are reading. The first Google hit mentions some embroidery machine file format. It might be a textual format, so you could start by testing whether `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(nameOfFile)` yields any useful output. Then create a dummy file (or rather, a unit test) that uses certain lines that do and don't contain the string you're trying to find. Only then you can create a [mcve] that others can actually help you with. The problem could very well be an encoding or casing one, both of which are trivial to solve once you have a clear problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @CodeCaster. I think the problem is pretty clear though - I don't know what a .xxx file is, how to work with one, or where to find help on one. You discovered what Google has to say about them, like I did. I would love to give an example of one, but that's just not possible - sorry! I recognize that, so I've tried to word the question so it's generic - how would any person in any circumstance find text in a .xxx file? If adding my specific situation is making the question confusing I can remove that or reword the question as "what is a .xxx file?" if that helps.

Comment: Try to read this question as someone who isn't you and who isn't looking at your screen. You're asking: _"I have this file in a very uncommon format for which I can't find a specification, it may or may not be a textual format, I won't provide its contents and I'm searching through it for a string I also won't provide. Why isn't my code working?"_. Nobody can answer that. Please read my previous comment again, there's debugging hints in there that can make this a viable question, read [mcve] and try [edit]ing your question. The point is, `"123foo456.Contains("foo")` will just work.

Comment: The least you could do is some debugging. Add in a `Console.WriteLine(line)` to see what it outputs. Someone likely just did something akin to, `File.WriteText(file.xxx)`; i.e., the .xxx extension is a red-herring, ignore it. If you can read it in notepad then it's very unlikely you can't read it with c#. Try all 5 encodings that [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) overload supports. Just because your method is returning 0 does *not* mean the text is being read incorrectly or not at all.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys, I'm going to re-write the question though. Apparently I didn't do a good job of making it clear what I'm asking for. That's my fault.

Comment: That's good to know, @Quantic. Do you know if .xxx is always a "red-herring" type of file extension? The one I have opens like a .txt file, but is .xxx just some sort of cover up that can be written onto the end of any type of file? (ie. it's possible one day I could stumble across one that opens as a spreadsheet, if someone chose to write that over the .xls?)

Comment: A file extension doesn't really mean anything. Windows reads an extension to *assume* it's openable with a program assigned to that extension. Programs themselves rarely read the file extension, they just read the bits of the file regardless of the extension. You can rename a `.xls` file to `.alamb` right now then `File-Open` it with excel and it will read it just fine. I have never heard of an .xxx extension before and considering notepad can read it appears you have a text file that someone gave a random extension of `.xxx` to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ReadLines, then it assumes it's a text file with line endings. If you're trying to use that on a binary file, then it won't necessarily work. And the best you may get is a count of 0 or 1, if there's no line endings found in the binary file at all.

You'll have to load the bytes in that instances and do a more thorough search through the binary file for instances of your string.

But if you're only wanting to know if a LINE contains at least one instance (as you have written your code above), then it won't work for binary files where you can't guarantee line endings exist.